# jenkins don't kill process under build step

Tags: python, shell, maven, jenkins, simplehttpserver

I have a Jenkins job with 2 Build steps

- Start a SimpleHTTPServer (Execute Shell)
- Maven test (Invoke maven target)

I am starting simpleHttpServer using the following command

> python -m SimpleHTTPServer 9000 &

But when I run the test, http server is not available. It seems that the process is killed as soon as the Execute Shell command is completed.

I read about spawning process from Jenkins job, but I don't want to keep the process running after the job is done, I just need it to be available for the next build step.

Comment: did you consider spawning off a process and add after test execution another shell step to kill that process?

Comment: I have not tried that, but that would mean if somehow build is stopped while running test, that process won't be killed, which means everytime I start the server i have to make sure that it is not already started

Comment: there is a port allocator plugin which would give you available ports only, so you could avoid that. Also, there is another plugin (any build step) which allows to you e.g. run execute shell as post build step - so you could ensure that process is always killed - independently if job was stopped prematurely or not.

Comment: Thanks for the response, instead of running separate build actions, i added mvn command to run the test in the Execute Shell build action.

Comment: @AshishMusale You can add an answer to your own question, and even accept it after 2 days, as well.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I solved the issue, I added a single Execute Shell build action and ran both the server and maven tests under that shell

```
python -m SimpleHTTPServer 9000 &
mvn test
```